# error in ssis execute sql task

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have placed a execute sql task inside the foreach loop container , where i want to execute the stored procedure name obtaining from the ssis user defined variable
But i am not finding a right syntax to execute stored procedure name from variable. and i want to pass input parameter to execute the stored procedure which is also a another dts variable
Please can any one help to figure out the right syntax

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say you have two variables `StoredProcedureName` and `ParameterValue`

Create a new variable called `QueryString`.  Open up the properties window by pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> and then click on the variable name in the window that has list of variables.  Set the `EvaluateAsExpression` property of your `QueryString` variable to True.

Then click  the elliptical in `Expression` to open up the **Expression Builder**.  Type the following expression

```
"Execute " + @[User::StoredProcedureName] + " @ParameterName = '" + @[User::ParameterValue]+ "'"
```

Click on **Evaluate Expression** and you should see

`Execute MyProcedure @ParameterName = 'SomeValue'`

Assign this variable to your `SourceVariable` for the **Execute SQL Task**.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i need one more help , here if my second variable @[User::ParameterValue] is integer value , how do i construct expression , its throwing type cast error

Answer (score 1):

You *can* build your string out as provided above but I would not start with it. For one, it assumes everything is string and second it could conceivably open you up to sql injection (highly improbable, I agree)

To actually use the native parameter mapping for ADO.NET you need to use the @PlaceHolder for your variable substitution. Based on your screenshot, the value of @[User::StoredProcedureName] would need to have the format of `EXECUTE schema.ProcName @ParameterName` Otherwise, you're looking at cobbling the expression from @Raj More's example without the `=...` piece

[image]

Mapping is as simple as the following. Ensure you select the correct Data Types and Parameter Names to correlate with your query.

[image]